# WebWorker Transferable Works on Chrome but not Firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, web-worker, typed-arrays

Here's [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jGyFJ/), which shows 100 on Chrome and 0 on FireFox.  Both tested on the latest stable release.

WebWorker code:

```
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    postMessage({len: event.data.arr.length});
};
```

And the main code:

```
var worker = new Worker("worker.js");

worker.onmessage = function(event) {
    console.log(event.data);
};

var arr = new Uint8Array(100);

worker.postMessage({
    arr: arr
}, [arr.buffer]);
```

Both support transferable arrays.  If I remove the `[arr.buffer]` argument it sends it over fine, but then I lose the performance gain, and it'll revert to structured cloning.

How can I make this work on both browsers, while keeping the transferable behavior?

(By the way, I'm actually using multiple arrays, and they total around 10MB).

Answer (score 1):

I've just been through this and asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20715568/web-workers-transferable-objects-working-differently-in-chrome-and-firefox-is) whether this is a bug or by design.

I came up with a workaround for this: even though the array has length zero and is apparently empty, its buffer is still there, and if you re-instantiate your array with that buffer, you can access your data:

```
// page:
worker.postMessage({
  arr: arr
}, [arr.buffer]);

// worker:
self.onmessage = function(event) {
  var arr = new Uint8Array(event.data.arr.buffer);
  postMessage({len: event.data.arr.length, arrLen: arr.length});
};
```

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/HLpwV/3/